# How to negate match_param on python? (pyramid)

Tags: python, pyramid

I want to be able to load the (localhost:6543/users),

[image]

it doesn't load because it requires a second parameter (ex. localhost:6543/users/x).

[image]

I'm aware of the problem, it is because I set it on my route.

```
config.add_route('users', '/users/{action}')
```

Here is my init.py

```
def includeme(config):
    config.add_static_view('user_static', 'user:static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_static_view('static', 'user:static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('users', '/users/{action}')
    config.scan()
```

here is my views.py

```
class UserView:

def __init__(self, request):
    self.request = request

@view_config(route_name='users', renderer='templates/users.jinja2')
def users(self):
    return {'title': 'Users'}


@view_config(route_name='users', renderer='json', match_param='action=list')
def list(self):
    #return list   

@view_config(route_name='users', renderer='json', match_param='action=add')
def add(self):
    #add new user

@view_config(route_name='users', renderer='json', match_param='action=getUser')
def getUser(self):
   #retrieve data for update

@view_config(route_name='users', renderer='json', match_param='action=updateUser')
def updateUser(self):
    #update record
```

Thank you for those who will answer, if you can give some improvements on my code, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I should use another route for all of my action here.

```
def includeme(config):
    config.add_static_view('user_static', 'user:static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_static_view('static', 'user:static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('users', '/users')
    config.add_route('action', '/action/{action}')
    config.scan()
```

and modify the views, change users to action.

```
class UserView:

def __init__(self, request):
    self.request = request

@view_config(route_name='users', renderer='templates/users.jinja2')
def users(self):
    return {'title': 'Users'}


@view_config(route_name='action', renderer='json', match_param='action=list')
def list(self):
    #return list   

@view_config(route_name='action', renderer='json', match_param='action=add')
def add(self):
    #add new user

@view_config(route_name='action', renderer='json', match_param='action=getUser')
def getUser(self):
    #retrieve data for update

@view_config(route_name='action', renderer='json', match_param='action=updateUser')
def updateUser(self):
    #update record
```

Comment: It is correct that you must define 2 routes here. One with the pattern and one without. It is not **strictly** necessary but it is the best approach. You could name the second one `user_action` with a pattern of `/users/{action}` or something if you wanted.